# How to match groups inside a specific delimiter in java regex

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

Consider a string :

```
<! Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support,----. If that happens the dream of most of the tough girls may come true. !> <!  dream of most of the tough girls may come true. !> <! Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support. !>
```

In the above string, I have used <! and !> as delimiter to specify paragraph boundaries, it is evident from the string that I have 3+1 sets of enclosing statements within delimiters.

The regex which I used to capture groups is

```
<!([^<!>].+)!>
```

The group it matches are:

```
Group 1: <! Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support,----. If that happens the dream of most of the tough girls may come true. !> <! dream of most of the tough girls may come true. !> <! Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support. !>

Group 2: Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support,----. If that happens the dream of most of the tough girls may come true. !> <! dream of most of the tough girls may come true. !> <! Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support.
```

I supposed the match to include three inner groups but it matches it only includes outer group as output.
Here is what I expected

```
//other groups

Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support,----. If that happens the dream of most of the tough girls may come true.

dream of most of the tough girls may come true.

Women's boxing is yet to be recognized as an Olympic support.
```

Comment: I think you can use `<!\s*(.*?)!\s*>` https://regex101.com/r/z4qaj2/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think ? did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `<!([^<!>].+)!>` starts the first character in the group matching any character except one of `<` `!` or `>`. Then the `.+` will match till the end of the  line and will backtrack until the first encounter of `!>`

If you don't want to capture the whitespace chars, you can match those at the beginning and the end and start the capture group with a non whitspace char `\S` to not match only whitspace chars.

Then use a lazy match until the first occurrence of `!>`

```
<!\s*(\S.*?)\s*!>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPHGlh/1)